# Gated Recurrent Unit and Long Short Term Memory

Tags: neural-network

Could somebody explain the similarities and dissimilarities between Long Short Term Memory(LSTM) and Gated Recurrent Unit(GRU) architectures. I know the definitions of each and that GRU lack an output gate and therefore have fewer parameters. Could somebody please give an intuitive explanation / analogy.

Comment: This sounds like you want us to do your homework for you. What's your understanding of the question? What part don't you understand?

Comment: I have been reading the wiki pages of each of them. I have a test. I know the definitions but missed a few lectures so don't really know how they work.

Comment: And there is not much on GRU's. It would be helpful if you could redirect me to some reading material. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the GRU architecture. However, this paper compares the LSTM and GRU architectures, I think it's exactly what you need.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.3555v1.pdf